# Cron commands work on SSH, but don't work on Cron(isp manager)

Tags: ssh, cron

i am running this in my putty SSH:

```
php $HOME/www/mysite.com/artisan
```

the command executes ok, but when i copy this to the isp manager, when creating a cron task, i get an error:

```
Exited with return code = 1
```

why is that happening or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the `cron` line.

Comment: is the same as it is in the ssh

Comment: What's the error text? What line gives the error?
Does the user creating the cron task have cron privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crontab jobs are scheduled using `crontab -e`. Then you can check what is in there by typing `crontab -l`.

A cronjob is like this:

```
* * * * * /route/of/binary /route/of/script
```

while * * * * * stands for:

- minute
- hour
- day of month
- month
- day of week

So if you want to execute an script every day at 10.30 you would write

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month   Month   Day of Week    Command     
* * * * * /bin/php /var/my-cron.sh
```

or whatever comes from `which php`.

Also, indicate full paths for whatever you are executing or files/dirs using.

Make sure the script has executing permissions for the user running the crontab.

Last but not least, edit crontab *always* with `crontab -e` and check what you have in it with `crontab -l`. If it is not working, check `/etc/cron.d/allow` and `/etc/cron.d/deny` to see if your user is there.

Comment: @reboot php $HOME/www/mysite.com/artisan Notify >/dev/null 2>&1
this is the cron line

Comment: do i have to remove those last lines /dev/null?, can you tell me what means the exited with error = 1?

Comment: It is ok to have `>/dev/null` at the end, to avoid error messages.

Comment: Also, change `php` for `/bin/php` or whatever comes from `which php`

Comment: i've changed php to /usr/bin/php, but i still get this error Exited with return code = 1, i don't what is it

Comment: Do you also have `$HOME` in the crontab? You should change it for a real value.

Comment: awesome man!, thank you very much for this help!!!, yeah the problem was in that variable $HOME

Comment: Crontab is a little tricky sometimes, it is stand alone and needs everything to be given "plain", without external variables. Good to read it works now : )